# Prevent Looping in my jQuery in ForEach Loop Laravel Reply System

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am building a .toggle function for my reply section.
Basically, click 'Reply' -> a textbox appear with a reply button' for that specific comment.

My reply section with display:none

```
 <div class="replyArea" style="display:none;" id="replyArea-{{ $comment->id }}">
      //code      
 </div>
```

Inside the foreach loop is my $comment->replies, each with a reply button

```
<a href="#" class="replyBtn">reply</a>
```

My jQuery is simple

```
$('.replyBtn').click(function(e) {

        commentId = $(this).closest('div').data('id');
        var id = '#replyArea-' + commentId;     
        $(id).toggle();
    })
```

This works in the FrontEnd, but when I console log the 'replyBtn', it was called 8-9 times depending on the number of replies there are because all the reply button have the same class. 
It will be better if the jQuery is set up towards a unique ID for each reply button but I currently have no clue how to do that.

Comment: Did you `consolelog(commentId)` to check if it really gets the correct `id` you want?

Comment: I did. And it get it like 8 times

Comment: You could try to add a `data-comment-id="{{ $comment->id }}"` to the reply button and access it with `var commentId = $(this).data('comment-id');`

Comment: Just to make sure: your "jQeury" code only appears _once_ in your page?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean 'jQuery' code only appear once?
If I use .toggle(), it works. But when I use .slideToggle() -> it will slide up and down a few times before finally slide down the reply section

Comment: Do you output/generate your jQuery code inside your loop? Or just once, outside your loop, as it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Just realise I am an idiot.

I was doing my jQuery inside a blade called 'commentdisplay' which is included in my 'show' blade.
So the layout looks sort of like this:

show.blade.php
    - commentdisplay.blade.php (@include commentdisplay.blade.php)

That's why I am getting a recurring console.log whenever I am doing my jQuery in my commentdisplay.blade.
Now I have moved that to show.blade.php and everything is fine.

Thank you all for the replies and suggestions!